# Quarkus / Hibernate - How to set a TTL to jdbc connection?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Our firewall system kills every connection after 30 minutes.

It killed a postgres JDBC connection once in our Quarkus application.

I want to avoid this behaviour by setting a TTL for jdbc connection in my quarkus `application.properties`

I did not find any explicit config to do so, except: `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-lifetime`

https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-agroal_quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-lifetime

Am I right ? Why is there no default value here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, that's the property you need to set.

You can for example do:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-lifetime=PT10M
```

if you want the connection to last up to 10 minutes.

As for why it's the default value, the answer is that there is no real default that would be a good fit for the various real world use cases.